# try-catch statement not returning to try block when catching exception

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a method that a wrote. This method just scans for a user entered integer input. If the user enters a character value it will throw an input mismatch exception, which is handled in my Try-Catch statement. The problem is that, if the user inputs anything that is not a number, and then an exception is thrown, I need the method to loop back around to ask the user for input again. To my understanding, a Try catch statement automatically loops back to the Try block if an error is caught. Is this not correct? Please advise.

Here is my method (it's pretty simple):

```
public static int getMask() {
        //Prompt user to enter integer mask
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int output = 0;
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter the encryption mask: ");
            output = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number, mask must be numeric");
        }
        return output;
    }//end of getMask method
```

Here is how the method is implemented into my program:

```
//get integer mask from user input
        int mask = getMask();
        System.out.println("TEMP mask Value is: " + mask);
```

/***************************************************************/
Here is my updated code. It creates an infinate loop that I can't escape. I don't understand why I am struggling with this so much. Please help.

```
public static int getMask() {
    //Prompt user to enter integer mask
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int output = 0;
    boolean validInput = true;

    do{
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter the encryption mask: ");
        output = keyboard.nextInt();
        validInput = true;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number, mask must be numeric");
        validInput = false;
        }
    }while(!(validInput));

    return output;
```

/************************************/FINAL_ANSWER
I was able to get it finally. I think I just need to study boolean logic more. Sometimes it makes my head spin. Implementing the loop with an integer test worked fine. My own user error I suppose. Here is my final code working correctly with better exception handling. Let me know in the comments if you have any criticisms.

```
//get integer mask from user input
        int repeat = 1;
        int mask = 0;
        do{
            try{

        mask = getMask();
        repeat = 1;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e){
                repeat = 0;
            }
        }while(repeat==0);
```

Comment: [The try block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html). No, it does not loop back.

Comment: Thanks I have read it but I am obviously missing a core concept

Comment: So I need a do-while loop then. Well that makes sense. I was just confused about how try-catch blocks work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my understanding, a Try catch statement automatically loops back to the Try block if an error is caught. Is this not correct?

It is indeed not correct. A `try` block will be executed only once.

You can use this to "work around" it (although [JasonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22440609/1093528) is more solid -- go with that):

```
boolean validInput = false;

while (!validInput) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter the encryption mask: ");
        output = keyboard.nextInt();
        validInput = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        keyboard.nextLine(); // swallow token!
        System.out.println("Please enter a number, mask must be numeric");
    }
}
return output;
```

Further note: you should NOT be catching `Exception` but a more specific exception class.

Comment: Thank you for responding with code, I really appreciate it. Telling me what I am doing wrong never helps unless I can visually see the correct answer for comparison. I will accept your answer when allowed.

Comment: Oh, one issue that I also missed; `nextInt()` will leave the token on the stream on failure.

Comment: Mine or @JasonC's... But please heed the advice about not catching `Exception`, you can really get into unexpected troubles if you do that

Comment: @JasonC so how to swallow it? `.next()` in the `catch` block?

Comment: @fge That's one option. Another option is `.next()` no matter what then `Integer.parseInt()`. Again it boils down to personal preference. A potential complication with `next()` in the handler is `next()` can also throw for other reasons -- not relevant to this situation (or even typical usage) but something to be aware of.

Comment: Alright, I changed my code using your tips but now I am stuck in an infinate loop. I also changed the exception to only handle the specific InputMismatchException. Please see my revised code above, I will edit it into my OP.

Comment: @AdamJ See comments re: `next()` and check out fge's updated code.

Comment: You should really go with @JasonC's solution, it is much more solid than mine

Answer (score 2):

> To my understanding, a Try catch statement automatically loops back to the Try block if an error is caught. Is this not correct?

No this is not correct, and I'm curious as to how you arrived at that understanding.

You have a few options. For example (this will not work as-is but let's talk about error handling first, then read below):

```
// Code for illustrative purposes but see comments on nextInt() below; this
// is not a working example as-is.
int output = 0;
while (true) {
    try{
        System.out.print("Enter the encryption mask: ");
        output = keyboard.nextInt();
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number, mask must be numeric");
    }
}
```

Among others; your choice of option usually depends on your preferred tastes (e.g. [fge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22440621/616460) is the same idea but slightly different), but in most cases is a direct reflection of what you are trying to do: "Keep asking until the user enters a valid number."

Note also, like fge mentioned, you should generally catch the tightest exception possible that you are prepared to handle. `nextInt()` throws a few different exceptions but your interest is specifically in an `InputMismatchException`. You are not prepared to handle, e.g., an `IllegalStateException` -- not to mention that it will make debugging/testing difficult if unexpected exceptions are thrown but your program pretends they are simply related to invalid input (and thus never notifies you that a different problem occurred).

Now, that said, `Scanner.nextInt()` has another issue here, where the token is left on the stream if it cannot be parsed as an integer. This will leave you stuck in a loop if you don't take that token off the stream. To that end you actually want to use either `next()` or `nextLine()`, so that the token is always consumed no matter what; then you can parse with `Integer.parseInt()`, e.g.:

```
int output = 0;
while (true) {
    try{
        System.out.print("Enter the encryption mask: ");
        String response = keyboard.next(); // or nextLine(), depending on requirements
        output = Integer.parseInt(response);
        break;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){ // <- note specific exception type
        System.out.println("Please enter a number, mask must be numeric");
    }
}
```

Note that this still directly reflects what you want to do: "Keep asking until the user enters a valid number, but consume the input no matter what they enter."

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, try-catch -blocks don't loop. Use a `for` or `while` if you want looping.

Comment: This is a good answer to the first question but it would be more useful it it posed a working alternative.